# having problems binding javascript to a submit button

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm having a problem binding this script to a submit button...

```
$('input').on('keydown', function(event) {
   var x = event.which;

   if (x === 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

I've done it before but it's been a long time and the examples on the web are not doing it for me. Thanks :)

Comment: Please post also your html code.

Comment: Wrap your code in a document ready function.

Comment: Try to put a html class or id to your input field then bind it on $.on()

Comment: You might try adding the type of input:  `$('input[type="submit"]')` if that makes more clear to you.  Some seem to think this MUST be in a document ready event handler and that is not the case as long as it exists prior to this statement. i.e. you might put this in a script at the END of your page body; otherwise you might need the placement of the keydown event handler in the document ready handler. You also might need it on the document itself instead of the input and prevent propagation.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(function($) { // DOM is now ready
  // your code here
});
```

should do the trick.
https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('input').on('keydown', function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 13 || e.which == 13) {
         e.preventDefault();
      }
   });
})
```

Please try this

Answer (score -2):

or you can try this code by using [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)

```
(function($) {
  $('input').on('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13 || e.which == 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```